# mysql combination search on field

Tags: php, mysql

table structure

categories table

```
id      name 
23      Rifle   
24      Bow 
26      Black Powder
```

Outfitters table

```
id    name
1     jignesh
2     Ram
3     Ravi
```

outfitters categories Table

```
id  outfitters_id  categories_id
1    1             23
2    1             24
3    1             26

4    2             23
5    2             26

6    3             26
```

Now my problem is when is select  (Rifle And Black Powder) Means (23,26) 
The result should be

```
1     jignesh
2     Ram
```

Current Query

```
SELECT distinct outfitters.id,
outfitters.name,
FROM outfitters 
LEFT JOIN categories as c1 ON (c1.categories_id='23') 
LEFT JOIN categories as c2 ON (c2.categories_id='26') 
WHERE outfitters.id=c1.outffiters_id 
OR 
outfitters.id=c2.outffiters_id 
AND outfitters.of_active=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT distinct outfitters.id,
outfitters.name,
FROM outfitters 
LEFT JOIN categories as c1 ON (c1.categories_id='23') 
LEFT JOIN categories as c2 ON (c2.categories_id='26') 
WHERE (outfitters.id=c1.outffiters_id 
OR 
outfitters.id=c2.outffiters_id) 
AND outfitters.of_active=1
GROUP BY outfitters.name
```

Okay, you could probably do this with a sub-query like this

```
SELECT name, id FROM(
    SELECT outfitters.name, outfitters.id, GROUP_CONCAT(outfitters_categories.categories_id) as gc
    FROM outfitters 
    JOIN outfitters_categories ON (outfitters.id = outfitters_categories.outfitters_id)
    WHERE outfitters_categories.categories_id IN (23,26) 
    GROUP BY outfitters.id ) 
tmp WHERE gc = "23,26"
```

And then you could simple replace 23,26 with whatever the user selects

Comment: it produced same result as earlier it provides me all three records as was earlier. i need record of outfitters who have selected both categories 23 and 26

Answer (score 0):

If you need the outfitters that must belong o your 2 categories you can do this by getting distinct count for each outfitter that must be > or = 2 and also with your where filter,see fiddle example according to the provided sample dataset

```
SELECT 
  o.* 
FROM
  Outfitters o 
  JOIN outfitters_categories oc 
    ON (o.id = oc.outfitters_id) 
WHERE oc.categories_id IN (23, 26) 
GROUP BY o.id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT oc.categories_id) >= 2
```

### [See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22f31/2)

Comment: there are 100 of categories user can select all of these and i need record of 100 categories combination

Comment: @jigneshparmar you can get the total count of categories select by user in php  right put that count at the end of having clause and put the categories id in where clause

Comment: it still does not give record perfect when you want to take it combination it does not work properly.

Comment: @jigneshparmar update your question with the query or php code how you are trying and also be precise regarding the problem *it still does not give record perfect* doesn't make any sense to me without knowing what wrong goes,also show your sample data set on which you are trying query